# How to divide students into N Section and every section to N groups PHP MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I would like to divide M students into sections and every section into groups, but there are some constraints :

1. The user who gives the number of sections and the number of groups from {input}
2. the section and the group will be inserted into the student table which contains "section_name" and "group_number"

I tried to do some PHP/MySQL code

```
if ((isset($_GET['grouper'])) && !empty($_GET['groupe']) && !empty($_GET['section'])) {


$get_etud_sec = $_GET['section'];
$get_etud_grp = $_GET['groupe'];
$database = getPDO();
$insert1 = $database->prepare("UPDATE L2 SET section = 'A' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_sec;");
$insert2 = $database->prepare(


    "UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '1' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '2' WHERE groupe != '1' AND section = 'A'ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '3' WHERE groupe != '1' AND  groupe != '2' AND section = 'A' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '4' WHERE groupe != '1' AND  groupe != '2' AND  groupe != '3' AND section = 'A' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '5' WHERE groupe != '1' AND  groupe != '2' AND  groupe != '3' AND  groupe != '4' AND section = 'A'ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '6' WHERE groupe != '1' AND  groupe != '2' AND  groupe != '3' AND  groupe != '4' AND  groupe != '5' AND section = 'A'ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '7' WHERE groupe != '1' AND  groupe != '2' AND  groupe != '3' AND  groupe != '4' AND  groupe != '5' AND  groupe != '6' AND section = 'A'ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '8' WHERE groupe != '1' AND  groupe != '2' AND  groupe != '3' AND  groupe != '4' AND  groupe != '5' AND  groupe != '6' AND  groupe != '7' AND section = 'A' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;"
);

$database = getPDO();
$insert3 = $database->prepare("UPDATE L2 SET section = 'B' WHERE section != 'A' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_sec;");
$insert4 = $database->prepare(
    "UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '1' WHERE section = 'B' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '2' WHERE groupe != '1' AND section = 'B' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '3' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND section = 'B' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '4' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND section = 'B' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '5' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND section = 'B' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '6' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND groupe != '5' AND section = 'B' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '7' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND groupe != '5' AND groupe != '6' AND section = 'B' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '8' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND groupe != '5' AND groupe != '6' AND groupe != '7' AND section = 'B' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;"
);
$database = getPDO();
$insert5 = $database->prepare("UPDATE L2 SET section = 'C' WHERE section != 'A' AND section != 'B' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_sec;");
$insert6 = $database->prepare(
    "UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '1'WHERE section = 'C' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '2' WHERE groupe != '1' AND section = 'C' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '3' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND section = 'C' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '4' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND section = 'C' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '5' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND section = 'C' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '6' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND groupe != '5' AND section = 'C' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '7' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND groupe != '5' AND groupe != '6' AND section = 'C' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '8' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND groupe != '5' AND groupe != '6' AND groupe != '7' AND section = 'C' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;"
);
$database = getPDO();
$insert7 = $database->prepare("UPDATE L2 SET section = 'D' WHERE section != 'A' AND section != 'B' AND section != 'C' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_sec;");
$insert8 = $database->prepare(
    "UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '1' WHERE section = 'D' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '2' WHERE groupe != '1' AND section = 'D' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '3' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND section = 'D' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '4' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND section = 'D' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '5' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND section = 'D' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '6' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND groupe != '5' AND section = 'D' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '7' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND groupe != '5' AND groupe != '6' AND section = 'D' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;
UPDATE L2 SET groupe = '8' WHERE groupe != '1' AND groupe != '2' AND groupe != '3' AND groupe != '4' AND groupe != '5' AND groupe != '6' AND groupe != '7' AND section = 'D' ORDER BY nom LIMIT $get_etud_grp;"
);
$insert1->execute();
$insert2->execute();
$insert3->execute();
$insert4->execute();
$insert5->execute();
$insert6->execute();
$insert7->execute();
$insert8->execute();
```

}

But unfortunately, I couldn't Set the code in a way that the user who give the number of section and the numbers of groups

Any ideas, please?